# Using Google Web Fonts with SASS/Compass -- how?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, google-font-api

Say I have this font: [Open Sans](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans)

If I want to use this with a SASS/Compass project, is there a better way to do it then linking to an additional stylesheet hosted by Google in order to be able to use the font?

Comment: You can alternatively download it and just reference it locally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for Google. Open Sans is.. well, open…  You can host the fonts yourself:

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/open-sans

If you want to be really fancy you can use Bourbon's font-face mixin:

http://bourbon.io/docs/#font-face

There's an excellent case to be made for letting Google (or Typekit, etc.) do the heavy lifting, but I prefer to control my own destiny and tend to favor self-hosting when possible. :)

Comment: I don't have much experience with hosting the fonts myself, does simply using them when it's in the root directory cause the user to download it if they don't have it?

Comment: The OP is using Compass, which has a mixin for custom fonts:  http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/font_face/

Comment: @DougSmith treat fonts like any other asset like images, scripts, etc. Usually best to store them in a directory unto themselves.

Answer (score 19):

Use the @import option:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
```

Or the JavaScript Option:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  WebFontConfig = {
    google: { families: [ 'Open+Sans::latin' ] }
  };
  (function() {
    var wf = document.createElement('script');
    wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
      '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
    wf.type = 'text/javascript';
    wf.async = 'true';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
  })(); </script>
```

Comment: Is the @import specific to SASS?

Comment: @DougSmith not sure what you're asking. Sass will interpret that as a [CSS import](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import) not a Sass partial import.

Comment: I keep getting an error when using the @import method for Google Fonts in my .scss sheet:

Invalid CSS after "@import url(http": expected comma, was "://fonts.google..."

Know what is going on?

Comment: Solved.  Need to drop the url(); and just put it directly within the quotes...."http://googleapis......"  Using Compass FYI